# apiary Auth login

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I am creating a apiary documentation for my API's.
My question is there a way we can declare a variable like now when i login with credentials i usually receive token so later when i call my API i usually send that token in the headers.

So what i am doing now is copy paste the token after i login in the headers, so i am curious if we can save the token while login and automatically send that token while calling my API's.

My headers are like

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : basic abcd
```

Comment: Where are you copy pasting the token? And where do you need to save it?

Comment: I am copy pasting it into headers while calling my api

Comment: i want to save it globally so that when i call my api after login it should take the token received while logging in automatically.

Comment: I meant to say how are you calling your API? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using java. like i need to save the response so that later i can use it

Comment: If you save the token in a variable, it can be overridden later when a different user logs in. So a better way to do it is to maintain the token in a database or a key-value store at backend or can be returned to the client side so the the client actually sends it with each request it makes to the backend.